# how to convert 3 integer to date format in SQL server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

There is following statements in my query:

```
declare @d int = day(getdate())
declare @m int = month(getdate())
declare @y int = year(getdate())
select @d,@m,@y
```

So I want to convert @d,@m,@y to date type(format) and use it as date parameter!
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a better example? Why are you not just using `getdate()`? Why are you fiddling with pulling things apart and changing data types? Just for the sake of it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @d int = day(getdate())
declare @m int = month(getdate())
declare @y int = year(getdate())

DECLARE @myDate DATETIME
SET @myDate = CAST (@y AS NVARCHAR(4))+'-'+CAST (@m AS NVARCHAR(2))+'-'+CAST (@d AS    NVARCHAR(2));

select @myDate
```

If u dont cast the values you will get some other date.

Comment: Doesn't work for everyone. If you add `set language british` above your code, then you get `The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it in a portable fashion:

```
select DATEADD(year,@y - 2000,DATEADD(month,@m - 1, DATEADD(day,@d - 1,
        '20000101')))
```

However, if your motivation was just to get the current date without any time portion, I'd just do:

```
select DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Or even

```
select CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

select *
from WeatherForecast
where Cast( cast(year as nchar(4)) + '-' + cast(month as nchar(2))  + '-'  + cast(day as nchar(2)) as date) between getdate() - 7 and getdate()

Comment: Please format your code and add some commentary explaining how it addresses the question and why it's different from other people's answers.

Comment: Code is formatted but, if you don't like how it looks, feel free to copy - paste into SQL query window and pretty it up.

Comment: As for how it's different - mine concatenates converts integers to strings then casts the resulting mess into a date var.

Comment: Aside from that - just another version in the event that folks dig mine.

Comment: I'm not on the receiving end of this answer, nor am I a moderator of the forum. This was just a friendly feedback to improve quality of your question. As it stands, it's more likely to attract downvotes and negative flags.